# Awaiting TaskCompletionSource across android activity navigations in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Im trying to create an awaitable method for gathering user input, that i can call from my viewmodel/core.
On android i want to present a new activity with input fields and an "OK"-button. Once the user hit OK, user-input-activity should be dismissed and the method should complete. Storing and managing the data is not a problem, but actually presenting the user-input-activity is.

I have a small project with a button that awaits this method. I can see an activity transition animation, but the (very simple) layout of MultiChoiceActivity is never actually shown.

```
    //### ViewModel
    public MvxAsyncCommand ShowListWithTitleCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _showListWithTitleCommand = _showListWithTitleCommand ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(() => DoShowListCommandAsync("Alt title"));
            return _showListWithTitleCommand;
        }
    }

    private async Task DoShowListCommandAsync(string title)
    {
        var bundle = new DialogServiceMultiItemsBundle(title, _allItems, _checkedItems.ToArray());
        var result = await _dialog.ShowMultipleChoice(bundle);
    }

    //### Awaitable method
    public Task<List<int>> ShowMultipleChoice(DialogServiceMultiItemsBundle bundle)
    {
        LastTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<int>>();
        LastBundle = bundle;

        CurrentContext.RunOnUiThread(() => {
            CurrentContext.StartActivity(typeof(MultiChoiceActivity));
        });

        return LastTcs.Task;
    }
```

How should i await this method across activity transitions? Adding async-await to the method seems to make no difference.

I've unsuccessfully tried Task.Run() to get off the UI thread (same behavior as above):

```
return await Task.Run<List<int>>(async () => { return await LastTcs.Task; });
```

Comment: Can we assume that you are calling `LastTcs.SetResult()` (or `LastTcs.SetException()` from the `MultiChoiceActivity` code?

Comment: Eventually i will be, yes. However, the activity navigation should trigger before SetResult() is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever started an activity with that overload in that way - I'm not sure you're initiating it properly. This is what I've always done, and maybe it's the key to your troubles?

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MultiChoiceActivity));
StartActivity (intent);
```

Or maybe (since it looks like you're in an MVVM context):

```
var intent = new Intent (CurrentContext, typeof(MultiChoiceActivity));
CurrentContext.StartActivity (intent);
```

The key difference here is using an explicit `Intent` to start the activity.

---

Other things to consider:

I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't need to use `RunOnUiThread()` when starting the activity.

Be sure to test simply hitting the Back button on the device after the activity is launched - I'm not sure the behavior there is what you would be expecting. This would potentially never give the activity a chance to call `SetResult()` or `SetException()` unless you code it to handle that case. Similarly, be sure to test it with an exception being thrown in either the load or unload of that activity. What you don't want is to return to your main activity with a zombie task being awaited.